# Not able to access a instance of a class from within a static procedure. C#

Tags: c#

I don't understand why this does not work for me. I am unable to access the instance of myList from within the procedure GetFiles(). If I copy the code and put it within a local scope it works fine. However, that is not really what I want to do because I want to access the myList object from other procedures and/or functions. Could someone please elaborate.

```
   GetFileList myList = new GetFileList(@"c:\temp");

   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetFiles();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void GetFiles()
    {
        //Gets files and lists last access time

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.fileList.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myList.fileList[i]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: **static** GetFileList myList...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `myList` like a static

```
static GetFileList myList = new GetFileList(@"c:\temp");
```

in order to be able to access it inside static method.

Or alternatively, pass it like a parameter

```
GetFileList myList = new GetFileList(@"c:\temp");

public static void GetFiles(GetFileList listOfFiles)
{
    //Gets files and lists last access time

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.fileList.Length; i++) //using param
    {
        Console.WriteLine(listOfFiles.fileList[i]); //using param

    }
}

GetFiles(myList);
```

Comment: Ok, that does make sense. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access intance fields from `static` methods because the `static` methods don't belong to any instance so you need to declare `myList` as `static`.